# Why am I getting this error when using glmnet in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

When trying to predict I am getting this error

```
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90
```

Here is my code so far

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(Metrics)
library(glmnet)
library(plotmo)
library(lubridate)

#Reading in the necessary data needed for this project

train <- fread("project/volume/data/processed/start_train.csv")
test<-fread("project/volume/data/processed/start_test.csv")
example_sub<-fread("project/volume/data/processed/example_submission.csv")
card_tab <- fread("project/volume/data/processed/card_tab.csv")


#Merging the card_tab dataset with both my train and test datasets to add more variables to each

train = merge(train, card_tab, by = "id")
test = merge(test, card_tab, by = "id")

train$power = as.numeric(train$power)
train$toughness = as.numeric(train$toughness)
test$power = as.numeric(test$power)
test$toughness = as.numeric(test$toughness)

train$powerovertough = train$power/train$toughness
test$powerovertough = test$power/test$toughness

train$current_date<-as_date(train$current_date)
train<-train[order(-current_date)]

test$current_date<-as_date(test$current_date)
test<-test[order(-current_date)]

#Handling NA values in both train and test. The NA values will be set to 0

train[is.na(train)] <- 0
test[is.na(test)] <- 0

# Specifying which columns of our model we will be dropping and applying it to our train and test datasets

drops<- c('id','future_date','current_date','card_name','power','loyalty','cmc','type','colors','mana_cost','subtypes', 'text','set','set_name')

train<-train[, !drops, with = FALSE]
test<-test[, !drops, with = FALSE]


#Saving the response variable in the train dataset

train_y<-train$future_price

test$future_price<-0

#Using dummies to train model

dummies <- dummyVars(future_price ~ ., data = train)
train<-predict(dummies, newdata = train)
test<-predict(dummies, newdata = test)

train<-data.table(train)
test<-data.table(test)

#Cross validating the model to fin the best lamda value

train<-as.matrix(train)
test<-as.matrix(test)

gl_model<-cv.glmnet(train, train_y, alpha = 1,family="gaussian")

bestlam<-gl_model$lambda.min

# Fitting the full model 

gl_model<-glmnet(train, train_y, alpha = 1,family="gaussian")

plot_glmnet(gl_model)

saveRDS(gl_model,"./project/volume/models/gl_model.model")

test<-as.matrix(test)

#use the full model
pred<-predict(gl_model,s=bestlam, newx = test)
```

I am trying to predict future_price for my test set. The error is saying my dimensions are wrong but I don't know what could be causing them to be different. I have tried observing the data sets as it runs through the code and they seem to have the same variables.

Here is the dput

```
> dput(head(train))
structure(c(0.25, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.25, 0.25, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("current_price", 
"typesArtifact", "typesArtifact Creature", "typesCreature", "typesEnchantment", 
"typesEnchantment Artifact", "typesEnchantment Creature", "typesInstant", 
"typesLand", "typesPlaneswalker", "typesSorcery", "supertypes", 
"supertypesBasic", "supertypesLegendary", "rarityCommon", "rarityMythic", 
"rarityRare", "rarityUncommon", "toughness", "powerovertough"
)))
```

```
> dput(head(test))
structure(c(0.15, 0.16, 2, 0.39, 0.16, 0.19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 18L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("current_price", "typesArtifact", "typesArtifact Creature", 
    "typesCreature", "typesEnchantment", "typesInstant", "typesLand", 
    "typesPlaneswalker", "typesSorcery", "supertypes", "supertypesBasic", 
    "supertypesLegendary", "rarityCommon", "rarityMythic", "rarityRare", 
    "rarityUncommon", "toughness", "powerovertough")))
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Could you please keep only the code before the line that creates the error? All the code after is irrelevant for the problem. I can't tell whether the error is the `cv.glmnet` call, the `glmnet` call, or something else.

Comment: Similarly, we don't have your data files, so we can't do much with your importing and processing code. The error you get is about the dimensions of the data, so please provide a bit of information about the data right before you get the error. In particular, the `dim()` (or `length()` if one-dimensional) for each of the `x` and `y` arguments, and a little bit of dput, e.g., `dput(head(train))` and `dput(head(train_y))` would be really helpful to see.

Comment: Okay, It is still a lot of code but I updated until I get an error

Comment: So, if it's the `predict` line that causes the error, please share `dput(head(test))` and `dput(head(train))` so we can see what your data looks like.

Comment: I just shared thank you

Comment: Your training data has 20 columns and your test data has only 18 columns. That is the issue - they need to have the same columns.

Comment: One other process note - you have a lot of lines that are doing the same thing for the training data and the test data. This is asking for bugs - a typo can easily create a difference between your training and test data. One way to improve your workflow is instead to create a function that takes in a data set, transforms/adds new features, and the returns the augmented data set. You can then run the function on both the training and test data sets and be sure you are doing the same thing to both of them (and avoid a lot of copy/paste/edit in your workflow).